# DELETE FROM for entries with same id, but leave the last one in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table that contains

```
id  username    password    last_touch
```

It is possible to have duplicate entries for the same id. The last_touch is the timestamp of the last insert command. How can I delete all entries with the same id, apart from the last one that is left so I always have the user details which are most up to date?

Somewhere along the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM user_data 
WHERE id=1 
LIMIT (count(SELECT 1 
             FROM user_data 
             WHERE id=1) - 1)
```

(Obviously the syntax is not correct in the above example, so MySQL complains.)

Comment: It depends on the declaration of id, is it auto incremented (which it should be) or do you add values to id yourself? If it is auto incremented I don't think you can have several entires with the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a nested query to select the latest timestamp for the given user id, and delete all rows for that id with timestamps different than that one:

```
DELETE FROM user_data
WHERE ID = 1 AND last_touch != 
    (SELECT latest FROM
        (SELECT MAX(last_touch) AS latest FROM user_data WHERE ID = 1) AS temp
    )
```

**Update:** Fixed direct reference to table being modified in inner `SELECT` by wrapping another `SELECT` around it, as per Frank's comments.

Comment: Hmm.. tried it, but I get "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: I think this is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: @FrankVilea: Indeed, I had forgotten about that restriction. Updated the answer with a working query.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM user_data u
WHERE id=1 
AND last_touch < (SELECT max(last_touch)
                  FROM user_data 
                  WHERE id=u.id)
```